# Is it possible to disable the cache in symfony 3 in dev environment?

Tags: symfony, caching

I'd like to disable the cache in the dev environment, but I can't.

I commented the line:

```
//$kernel->loadClassCache();
```

In the `app_dev.php` file but in the cache folder (`var/cache/dev`) Symfony still writes cached files.

Is there any way to let Symfony work without cache?

Comment: Why would you want this ? If you don't want cache, use app.php not app_dev.php.

Comment: I want all the others features of the app_dev. But sometimes, I noticed that symfony didn't read my changes becouse of the cache. So wath I do now is run the commant to clear the cache. Furthermore also the app.php has the cache enabled.

Comment: Which changes ?

Comment: For instance: i changed a twig file and it still use the old one. I fixed an error and it still shows me the error...

Comment: Twig templates are not cached. Your environment must be broken.

Comment: but there's a twig folder in the cache dir

Comment: Yes, but the file cache corresponding to your template should be regenerated each time the file changes. To answer you 1st question: Is there any way to let Symfony work without cache? > no

Answer (score 1):

In Symfony 4 I create a new twig.yaml file under /config/packages/dev/ with following lines:

```
twig:
    cache: false
```

And don't touch common /config/packages/twig.yaml. It works fine.